# How to use one collection to map another collection in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a dataset like the following

```
[{id:1,month:1,count:1},{id:1,month:2,count:2},{id:1,month:3,count:3}......,
{id:2,month:1,count:1},{id:2,month:2,count:2},{id:2,month:3,count:3}.......,
........
........
{id:19,month:1,count:1},{id:19,month:2,count:2},{id:19,month:3,count:3}.......,]
```

and the table looks like this.

```
|id|month|count|
|1 |  1  | 1   | 
.............
.........
|19| 12  | 4   |
```

there is another id as divisonId and it maps to the ids above as the following

```
{1:[1,2,4,5],2:[3,6,8,9],3:[7,10,....19]}
```

and the mapping table looks like this.

```
|divisionId| id|
|    1     | 1 |
|    1     | 2 |
|    1     | 4 |
|    1     | 5 |
|    2     | 3 |
|    2     | 6 |
......
......
```

so now I need to aggreate the data and sum and regroup them according to the divisonIds.

so eventually the return data should look like the following

```
[{divsionId:1,month:1,count:19},{divisionId:1,month:2,count:53},{divisionId:1,month:3,count:66}......,
    {divisionId:2,month:1,count:21},{divisionId:2,month:2,count:82},{divisionId:2,month:3,count:63}.......,   
    {divisionId:3,month:1,count:1},{divisionId:3,month:2,count:2},{divisionId:3,month:3,count:3}.......,]
```

and the table should looks like

```
| divisionId| month | count |
|     1     |   1   |  200  |
|     1     |   2   |  400  |
|     1     |   3   |  300  |
.....
.....
|     3     |   11  |  500  |
|     3     |   12  |  600  |
```

so basically, it just map the ids to divisionId, and sum up the individually months across those ids and aggregate a new collection to return data.
I am not allowed to put divisionId to the original table, due to the fact that ids maybe assigned to different divisionIds in the future, or it could have been much easier to just use the aggregate methods.

currently, one way I can do so is to use Javascript to get datas for ids separately according to the mapping, then do the calculation and push it up to mongos to store it as a new collection, so when UI query the data in the future, it will just read the query, saving the expensive calculation. But it would be awesome if I can solve this problem just by using some advanced mongodb syntax. Please let me know if you have some tricks I could use. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
db.divisionIdCollName.aggregate([{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "idCollectionName",
        let: { ids: "$id" },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match:
                {
                    $expr:
                        { $in: ["$id", "$$ids"] }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "data"
    }
}, { $unwind: { path: "$data", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $group: { _id: { divisionId: '$divisionId', month: '$data.month' }, month: { $first: '$data.month' }, count: { $sum: '$data.count' } } },
{$addFields : {divisionId : '$_id.divisionId'}}, {$project : {_id:0}}
])
```

**Result :** [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/evR7grzYIjV)

You can test results over there - Once you feel aggregation is returning correct results try to add [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#examples) stage to write result to another collection, you could use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) instead of `$merge` but we're using `$merge` is because if given name matches with any collection name in database `$out` will replace entire collection with aggregation result each time query runs which is destructive & should not be used if this query has to update existing records in a collection, Which is why we're using `$merge`, Please read about those two before you use, So add below stage as last stage after `$project`.

**Note :** `$merge` is new in `v 4.2`, `$out` >= `v 2.6`. If you're doing `$merge` since you're specifying two fields `on: [ "divisionId", "month" ]` - So there should be an unique compound index created on collection `divisionIdCollNameNew` - So yes we need to manually create collection & create unique index as well & then execute query.

**Create collection & index :**

```
db.createCollection("divisionIdCollNameNew")     
db.divisionIdCollNameNew.createIndex ( { divisionId: 1, month: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

**Final Stage :**

```
 { $merge : { into: { coll: "divisionIdCollNameNew" }, on: [ "divisionId", "month" ], whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

### ASSUMPTION

Collection `months` has this structure:    `{id:1,month:1,count:1}`

Collection `divisions` has this structure: `{1:[1,2,4,5],2:[3,6,8,9],3:[7,10,19]}`

You may perform such query:

```
db.divisons.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
          },
          cond: {
            $isArray: "$$this.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "months",
      let: {
        ids: "$data.v"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$id",
                "$$ids"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "months"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$months"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        divisionId: "$data.k",
        month: "$months.month"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: "$months.count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      divisionId: "$_id.divisionId",
      month: "$_id.month",
      count: "$count"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      divisionId: 1,
      month: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s9JMu01u7xJ)

### EXPLANATION

Your `divisions` collection has not normalized `key:value` pairs, so our first step is to convert `1:[...], 2:[...]` pair into `[{k:"1", v:[...]}, {k:2, v:[...]}]` pairs with `$objectToArray` operator.

Then, we flatten array from previous step with `$unwind` and apply `$lookup` with [uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to cross with `months` collection.

The last steps, we `$group` by `divisionId + month` and sum `count` value.

In order to store the result inside another collection, you need to use [$out or $merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#comparison-with-merge) operator.